# info.plist is not saving changes made

Tags: react-native, geolocation, info.plist

I have been trying to edit my info.plist to use geolocation, every time I do I save the file but when re-running the build it reverts back to its default form without the changes. Can anyone please help, below is the file in question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LastAccessedDate</key>
    <date>2019-07-03T05:00:01Z</date>
    <key>WorkspacePath</key>
    <string>/Users/JingoLine/repAsc/ios/repAsc.xcworkspace</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your location is required for xyz benefits for you</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

on Re-run it goes back to :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>LastAccessedDate</key>
        <date>2019-07-03T05:00:01Z</date>
        <key>WorkspacePath</key>
        <string>/Users/JingoLine/repAsc/ios/repAsc.xcworkspace</string>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: are you trying this in Xcode?

Comment: No, I am using VS Code

Comment: try it in Xcode. it shuld work

Comment: It does, but I am still not getting any request for location sharing. But that is for another Question I guess. You can post as an answer to validate